# Spring: RestTemplate messageConverters are not registered

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have an issue with the registration of the `messageConverters` on the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`.

I have tried (with no effect) two solutions:

**1)** Defining a bean of restTemplate in the Spring configuration, with all the converters that I need:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" autowire-candidate="true">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="test.myApp.MyHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**2)** Declaring the messageConverters in the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="test.myApp.MyHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

I also used the attribute `register-defaults="true"`

With both of these two solutions, the restTemplate instance contains only the same 6 default converters:

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
StringHttpMessageConverter
ResourceHttpMessageConverter
SourceHttpMessageConverter
AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter
```

**There is no trace** of the `test.myApp.MyHttpMessageConverter` and of the `org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter`.

I'm using the 4.3.1.RELEASE version of Spring.

How to make possible the registration of the messageConverters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using the `RestTemplate`?

Comment: It's invoked automatically in the `org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` component, I'm not managing it manually.

Comment: Then how are you injecting the template into the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandle‌​r` if you don't tell it to use your instance it will use the default one.

Comment: Exactly, the problem was exactly this one. I have already posted the solution! Thanks however for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Since I'm using the Spring Integration `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` component, I need to add the attribute `"rest-template"` in the outbound-gateway.

So, **the working solution is the (1)** that I posted above, **together with this configuration**:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway rest-template="restTemplate" ... />
```

Otherwise, it will be used a default rest-template (without custom messageConverters).